# jacoco android gradle plugin empty report on android kotlin project after bumping android gradle plugin to version 3 (beta)

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco, android-studio-3.0

On a android project written in kotlin I'm using jacoco-android-gradle-plugin to generate the code coverage report for unit tests.

The report is fine when using version 2.3.3 of the android gradle plugin, but it's empty when upgrading to version 3 (beta). Same behaviour on Android Studio 3 (beta) when setting the jacoco code coverage runner (not the built-in intellij one).

I know the android gradle plugin 3 and android studio are still in beta, but I was wondering whether there is a workaround for this?

Alessandro

Comment: see this relevant Issue on [google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64929213)